# Alexa skill in java not waiting for response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm trying the WiseGuy sample app in Java and can get Alexa to say "knock knock" but then the light turns off and that's it, I don't get to say "who's there".

Same issue with my own skill, even though I'm using newAskResponse(). Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks!

Etienne

Comment: Way more info is needed.  Please read this when posting: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by using the jar file produced by Maven instead of directly using the source code. Not sure why that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

When you face issues like this, don't forget, you can use the skill configuration "Test" tab, to test the skill, to make sure it's not an interpretation problem (which can happen often).

Also, if doing that still gives you a response that you are not expecting you can copy that intent request:

[image: screenshot]

And that past it on your lambda function event Test, there you will be able to see a more detail "debug" and if you are still not sure, make sure you do a few prints to at least pin point where the issue is:)